# How to scrape website source code with Google Sheets/ Google Apps?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to import some of the data hidden in source code of the website. S

ince this particular piece of information is not displayed on page I can't use xpath. I thought it wold be easier to import whole source code to Google Sheets and extract required data step by step. Could you please suggest best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the data not being visible to the eye, it may still be accessible via [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). That happens because the information may still be part of the "nodes" in the DOM; despite those being set as hidden by styling. You can navigate those nodes by [parsing the HTML](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html).

Other than that, another great solution is to use Regular Expressions. You can use this solution combined with above. I suggest you use the following links if you choose to go this way:

- [Using regular expressions in Google Apps Script](https://scriptingwithshiva.blogspot.com/2018/04/google-apps-script-regular-expressions.html). Overview of using regex's in GAS.
- [Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/). Can be very useful to testing your regular expressions.

Finally, it may be that the data is dynamically loaded using Javascript. If that is the case, you will not be able to get the data just by making the standard HTTP request to the webpage, but rather, you will have to understand the requests that are happening and, if possible, request them yourself from GAS.

If this does not solve your issue please do consider sharing an example of the webpage you are trying to get the data from, so we can provide tailored answers.